# How to create nexted columns with bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create nexted columns with bootstrap grid, but the result I'm getting isn't nexted

```
 {% for home in home %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 med_trend bg-light shadow m-4 rounded">
                    <h3 class="text-center text-info">{{ home.title }}</h3>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check text-info mr-2"></i>{{ home.first_point }}</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check text-info mr-2"></i>{{ home.second_point }}</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check text-info mr-2"></i>{{ home.third_point }}</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check text-info mr-2"></i>{{ home.fourth_point }}</li>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

[image]

Comment: what does nexting mean? Nested? Can you provide a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Lolo please check, I just added a picture

Comment: You may want to post the code that creates the output. Otherwise getting help here is difficult. Please check: https://nimb.ws/Sb50wk This is how your current code looks like.

Comment: Thanks @m4n0. When everything is on frontend the grid works perfectly as the one in the picture you posted. But I'm retrieving the data from database using django. So if I duplicate the code inside of `<div class="row">...</div>`, each group of data in the database will be retrieved twice; that is why I'm looping through the query from the database. The issue I'm facing now is that the columns are nexted when all the data is on frontend, but when querying it from the database and looping through it in the html, the columns are not nexted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**> you shlould add row and container outside the loop**

```
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

 {% for home in home %}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 med_trend bg-light shadow m-4 rounded">
                    <h3 class="text-center text-info">{{ home.title }}</h3>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check text-info mr-2"></i>{{ home.first_point }}</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check text-info mr-2"></i>{{ home.second_point }}</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check text-info mr-2"></i>{{ home.third_point }}</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check text-info mr-2"></i>{{ home.fourth_point }}</li>
              
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
  </div> 
            </div>
```